# Images in posters

Tags: graphics, posters

I am using the template from [Elena Botoeva](http://www.inf.unibz.it/~ebotoeva/fancytikzposter.html) to create an A0 poster. How do I insert figures (pdf) into each node? I am guessing that `\usepackage{graphicx}` will be needed but it keeps giving errors saying that there are too many closing brackets, `}`.

Comment: Start by compiling the example file that is linked to on that site.  It would be nice to know if that works, before trying to fix problems with graphics. Then try `\includegraphics{}` in one of the boxes that is defined in the example.

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First include the [graphics](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphics) package in the preamble.

```
\usepackage{graphics}
```

Then just use

```
\includegraphics{oohapicture}
```

within one of the `\blocknode` environments that are defined.

For example, to include a picture in the *Personalizing the Poster* section of the example, use this:

```
\blocknode {Personalizing the Poster}%
{It is possible to adjust the layout of the poster. To impose your own setting, you can use these macros:

\includegraphics{oohapicture}

\begin{itemize}
...
```

and it should work fine.

If you have two files with different extensiosn (e.g. .eps and .pdf), and you desperately want to use the pdf, just add the extension to the file name:

```
\includegraphics{oohapicture.pdf}
```

Comment: I was using begin figure and end figure, does it have to be an eps file because mine are pdf's.

Comment: don't you need to specify what file the picture is? It just comes up with package pgf error, no shape named firestrow is known

Comment: As far as I can tell, you just have to follow the rules for the `includegraphics` command. So eps is not *required*.

Comment: Put your image in the same directory as the .tex source for the poster. If the filename is MyImage, use `\includegraphics{MyImage}`. try with and without the extension.

Comment: it is in the same folder just checked, still get that error though

Comment: @user21119 note that if you use `\usepackage{graphics}` rather than `\usepackage{graphicx}` that will help. You can also put the extension in the file name. I've updated the answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8718/discussion-between-lostbrit-and-user21119)